# Add Worksheet To Current Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

My syntax below adds a worksheet to a new workbook, how can I add to the same workbook?

```
private void AddWorksheetsAndCopyData()
{
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlApp.Visible = true;
    Excel.Worksheet addedSheet;
    string filePath = @"C:\sample.xlsx";
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

    //checking if cell value is null - if it is not adding worksheet to copy data to

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    addedSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add();

    range.Copy(newSeet.Range["A1"]);
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote?  I provided syntax I tried, and clearly described the problem,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(After: xlWorkBook.Sheets[xlWorkBook.Sheets.Count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
newWorksheet.Name = "New Sheet";